# menu is not coming on top right side corner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

In virtual mobile menu is displaying.But it is not displaying in my personal mobile.I have kept `mainactivity.java` ,`main.xml`,`androidmainfest.xml` files here.Any answers please...

```
//mainactivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    String username,password;     ResultSet rs =null;
    boolean temcfag=false;
    static boolean temqfag=true;
    public static String tag="Lifecycle activity";
    EditText user,pass;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setNeutralButton("OK", null);


        user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
           final Button click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);       
           click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                            
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                          {             
Intent launchactivity= new Intent(MainActivity.this,com.example.desisquarea.LoginActivity.class);                               
startActivity(launchactivity);                          
                            }
                             });   

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}



//menu/main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/login" android:title="SignUP" />
<item android:id="@+id/sign" android:title="Login" />
<item android:id="@+id/home" android:title="Home" />
</menu>



//androidmainfest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.desisquarea"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.desisquarea.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What version of Android is your smartphone running?

Answer (score -1):

```
     LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
      lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
     myDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
     dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.where should i want keep this code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am beginner learner of android.It showing error for 'myDialog'should i want replace the 'myDialog' word with any thing?

Comment: you replace it with the name of your dialog.In your case it is 'dialog'.

Comment: Please add this line aswell            ' dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp); '

Comment: and where is your diaog.show();? It is required to show the dialog...Please accept the answer if this solution has worked .. :)

Comment: showing error you can't use 'getWindow()' for 'dialog' in 'dialog.getWindow()'

Comment: Use Dialog dialog;dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
   dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);        mian_menu is your own layout which you wanna inflate in your dialog...

Comment: showing error you cant use 'setContentView(R.layout.main_menu)' for 'dialog'

Comment: You should really be more explicit, an answer containing just a code snippet can't be a good answer.

Comment: what you expect give entire ready made code.There should be efforts from your side aswel ...